# Is there anyway to generate HAR file without setting up Proxy?

Tags: java, json, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, performance-testing

I want to extract all the resources under Network tab of Dev tools. The solution I found is using HAR file which in turn uses Proxy settings. But, I don't want to set up any Proxy.

In my selenium, I am navigating to different pages. When each page is loaded completely, I want to extract the network traffic to a JSON or HAR file.

So please help to achieve it in Java and Selenium. Below links I found which is of no use:

[Link 1](https://github.com/Filirom1/browsermob-page-perf)

[Link 2](http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/http-archive-specification/)